# Microsoft Word 2016 page number to be 3 digits (001, 002, 003, ...)

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I have the following problem when trying to change the page numbering format.
The change is from 1 to a format 001,...099, etc

I have tried the way they indicated (this `{PAGE \ # "000"}` and this `{NUMPAGES \ # "00#"}`) however it did not work, it does not update when I press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Could you tell me how to do it in Word 2016?

Answer (score 0):

It already worked, if pressing the <kbd>F9</kbd> key does not update it, try with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. This last one worked for me.